Squarify: adjust placement of groups within the plot
I am interested in generating a tree map plot for a dataset using squarify.
Below is the code and my questions:
pip install squarify

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import squarify

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['segment', 'count'])

segment = ['med time, hi freq', 'med time, low freq', 'med time, med freq',
          'quick time, hi freq', 'quick time, low freq', 'med time, med freq',
          'slow time, hi freq', 'slow time, low freq', 'slow time, med freq']

count = [8700, 57000, 8500, 7500, 95500, 10000, 1700, 54000, 3600]

df['segment'] = segment
df['count'] = count

df

df
# desired order
sizing = [54000, 3600, 1700, 57000, 8500, 8700, 95500, 10000 ,7500]

tree_map_labels = ['slow time, low freq', 'slow time, med freq', 'slow time, hi freq',
                    'med time, low freq', 'med time, med freq', 'med time, hi freq',
                   'quick time, low freq', 'quick time, med freq', 'quick time, hi freq']

# plot
fig = plt.gcf()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
fig.set_size_inches(10,6)

# squarify.plt(sizes=df['count'], label=df['segment'], ec='white', alpha=0.6, norm_x=5, norm_y=5)
squarify.plot(sizes=sizing, label=tree_map_labels, ec='white', alpha=0.6, norm_x=5, norm_y=5)

plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('frequency')

plt.show()

squarify plot
More context:
The segment map below is used earlier in the code to assign the segments within another df. Each row is assigned two values (each is 1-5 - the reason for norm_x and norm_y in the plot arguments to be 5), which is how the segment is determined.
segment_map = {
    r'[1-2][1-2]': 'slow time, low freq',
    r'[1-2][3]': 'slow time, med freq',
    r'[1-2][4-5]': 'slow time, hi freq',
    r'[3][1-2]': 'med time, low freq',
    r'[3][3]': 'med time, med freq',
    r'[3][4-5]': 'med time, hi freq',
    r'[4-5][1-2]': 'quick time, low freq',
    r'[4-5][3]': 'quick time, med freq',
    r'[4-5][4-5]': 'quick time, hi freq'
}

The df provided above is simplified for the question, however in reality it is just a groupby of segments and counts of the number of occurrences of each segment, like so:
df[['segment','count']].groupby('segment').agg('count').reset_index()

Questions:

Considering the segment map, is there any other way to ensure the plot will obey the borders provided in the segment map?
Ideally I'd like to provide squarify with the df columns respectively for sizes and label arguments, rather than manually specifying the order of groups and labels in sizing and tree_map_labels. I tried providing them directly, however the placement of all groups is not right (see commented code in the plot section). Is there any way to provide the df columns, but still maintain the required order stated in the segment map?

All I could find related to squarify is that the label and groups should be provided in the same order, however, I am not sure how can I control the order of groups so they'd stick to the order and borders I need them to be in, while still maintaining the group sizes/proportions.
Thanks in advance!
